# Controls jump to max. possible width as soon as margin or padding is set

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an application using c#/WPF and .NET 4.6 and have a very strange problem which never happend before:

I have a `Window` containing a `UserControl`. The windows has `SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight` set and the user control contains the following `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainText}" />

    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdditionalText}"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{DynamicResource Icons.Colored.Info}" />

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentCheckName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentCheckInfo}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PastChecks}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This still works fine and the window is as big as it needs to be.
BUT if I now change e.g. the `ProgressBar` to:

```
 <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Margin="10"/>
```

The window resizes to the max. possible width which is either `MaxWidth` if set or the width of all of my monitors.

I do not understand why this is happening as it never happend to me before and I have no idea what I did different this time.
Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Why Grid.Row = "1" ? Where is this Grid defined?

Comment: @o_weisman: Ups, that was from another try with a `Grid` instead of the `StackPanel` which did not change anything...

Comment: I cannot replicate this by having a window with a progress bar inside a stack panel: the window sizes correctly regardless of whether I set a margin on the progress bar or not. Also, copying and pasting your XAML works fine for me (although none of the bindings work, obviously). Are you styling any of the controls differently? If so, may be an issue with the progress bar style you're using.